# Windows 10/SAP fonts

Tags: windows-10, fonts, sap

I recently had to buy a new laptop and reinstall all my software. When I Installed SAP GUI 740 the font is extremely small. With all the other apps I could increase the size using the standard methods already published here and on other sites, SAP GUI however was not updated or affected by these changes. How do I fix is so that the font in the GUI is "Normal"?

Answer (score 0):

[SAP has online help on changing the font size.](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/c8/e53c418f35ef23e10000000a155106/content.htm):

"To change the font and the font size in accessibility mode, proceed as follows:

1. In SAP GUI for Windows, choose Local Layout → Options. You can also use the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> (for Local Layout) and then press the key <kbd>O</kbd> (for Options).
2. In the Options dialog box, choose the Fonts tab page.
3. Set the fonts and font sizes that you want to use.

You can either choose one of the predefined font sizes (small, medium, large) or make your own setting. You can then view the results of your settings in the preview window.

4. Choose OK.
5. After changing the font or font size, we recommend that you close and restart all SAP programs."